# Manipulate a tree layer wise

Tags: haskell, tree

I built a tree in `Haskell` where every node has a number that is unique in its path from root to leaf. Nodes have a dedicated list for children that are leaves. Because the tree is very large I want to unify (i.e. keep the right one, replace the left one with a link) sub trees that are equal by some metric. For this and similar tasks I wrote the `treewalker` function that walks through all nodes of a certain depth and applies a function that has access to already visited nodes via a generic cache.

`treewalker` can then be called with several functions that specify how to process each node. In the example provided I link to already seen sub trees whose path is a permutation of the path to the current node. But I use several other functions with different purposes, so I want to keep the cache general and the function that is applied to each node as well.

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- needed for treewalker

data LinkedTree = LinkedNode Int   -- index of node
                             [Int] -- leaf indices
                             [LinkedTree] -- children

                | Link  Int -- index of node
                        [Int] --path to the linked node
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

newtype Path        = Path [Int]
newtype ListCache a = ListCache [a]

type PathCache = ListCache Path

class Cache a where
  cacheAdd   :: b -> a b -> a b
  emptyCache :: a b 

instance Cache ListCache where
   cacheAdd   p (ListCache x) = ListCache (p:x)
   emptyCache = ListCache []

-- walks through all nodes of specified depth and applies a function
treeWalker :: forall c a. (Cache c) => (LinkedTree -> [Int] -> c a -> (LinkedTree, c a)) -- function to apply on every node of desired depth
           -> Int --depth
           -> LinkedTree
           -> LinkedTree
treeWalker processNode desiredDepth lnode = fst $ helper [] emptyCache lnode
  where
    helper :: [Int] -- path up until now, excluding current node, [level k, ..., level 1, root]
           -> c a
           -> LinkedTree
           -> (LinkedTree, c a)
    helper _    cache (Link is p)           = (Link is p, cache)           -- there may be links already e.g. from a previous run with different parameters
    helper path cache (LinkedNode is lis children) | tooShortNoChildren = (LinkedNode is lis [], cache) -- path ends too soon,  return cache as is
                                                   | notDeepEnoughYet   = (LinkedNode is lis children', cache') --not deep enough, recurse
                                                   | atDesiredDepth      = processNode (LinkedNode is lis children) path cache
                                                   | otherwise = error "unexpected"
                                                 where
                                                     tooShortNoChildren = length path < desiredDepth && null children
                                                     notDeepEnoughYet   = length path < desiredDepth
                                                     atDesiredDepth      = length path == desiredDepth 
                                                     (children', cache') = foldl g ([], cache) children -- we use fold because we need the first childs result for the second child
                                                     g :: ([LinkedTree], c a) -> LinkedTree -> ([LinkedTree], c a)
                                                     g (processed, cache) lt =  (processed++[p2], c2)
                                                             where
                                                                p2 :: LinkedTree
                                                                c2 ::  c a
                                                                (p2,c2) =  (helper (head is:path)) cache lt

setPermutationLinks :: Int -> LinkedTree -> LinkedTree 
setPermutationLinks = treeWalker processNode 
  where
    processNode :: LinkedTree -> [Int] -> PathCache -> (LinkedTree, PathCache)
    processNode ln@(LinkedNode is _ _) path cache = case query cache of
                        Nothing   -> (ln, cacheAdd fullPath cache)  --return node as is, add path to cache
                        Just cpath -> (Link is $ reverse cpath, cache)  --return link, and unchanged cache

         where
          currentPathMatches (a:as) = head is == a  -- both end in the same node
                                   && Set.fromList path == Set.fromList as -- remaining are identical
          fullPath = Path $ head is:path
          query :: PathCache -> Maybe [Int] -- its in the cache or not
          query (ListCache [])                            = Nothing
          query (ListCache (Path a:as)) | currentPathMatches a = Just a
                                        | otherwise            = query $ ListCache as
```

The above code works, but I found it hard to come up with and difficult to debug. Is there a clearer way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

`tooShortNoChildren` is subsumed in `notDeepEnoughYet`. The newtypes and class are silly, discard them. `treeWalker` doesn't touch `cache`, so let's hide `cache` in a monadic interface.

```
-- walks through all nodes of specified depth and applies a function
treeWalker :: ([Int] -> LinkedTree -> State [a] LinkedTree) -- function to apply on every node of desired depth
           -> Int -> LinkedTree -> LinkedTree
treeWalker processNode desiredDepth = (`evalState` []) . helper [] processnode
  where
    helper :: Monad m => [Int] -- path up until now, excluding current node, [level k, ..., level 1, root]
           -> ([Int] -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree)
           -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree
    helper _ cache (Link is p) = (Link is p, cache) -- there may be links already e.g. from a previous run with different parameters
    helper path cache ln@(LinkedNode is lis children) =
      if length path == desiredDepth
        then processNode path cache ln
        else LinkedNode is lis <$> traverse (helper (head is:path)) children
```

The explicit recursion has the form of a fold.

```
-- walks through all nodes of specified depth and applies a function
treeWalker :: ([Int] -> LinkedTree -> State [a] LinkedTree) -- function to apply on every node of desired depth
           -> Int -> LinkedTree -> LinkedTree
treeWalker processNode desiredDepth = (`evalState` []) . foldr ($) processNode (replicate desiredDepth step) []
  where
    -- Makes a node processor work at one level deeper.
    -- The path excludes the current node and has form [level k, ..., level 1, root].
    step :: Monad m => ([Int] -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree) -> [Int] -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree
    step _ _ l@(Link _ _) = return l
    step f path ln@(LinkedNode is lis children) = LinkedNode is lis <$> traverse (f . (head is:)) children
```

I'd inline that.
I'll assume that comparing `a:as` and `head is:path` is enough. I'll also assume that as according to `LinkedNode`s definition, its first parameter has type `Int`, not `[Int]`.

```
setPermutationLinks :: Int -> LinkedTree -> LinkedTree 
setPermutationLinks desiredDepth = (`evalState` []) . foldr ($) processNode (replicate desiredDepth liftThroughTree) [] where
  processNode :: [Int] -> LinkedTree -> State [[Int]] LinkedTree
  processNode path ln@(LinkedNode i _ _) = gets (find $ (Set.fromList (i:path) ==) . Set.fromList) >>= \case
    Nothing -> modify ((i:path):) >> return ln
    Just cpath -> return $ Link i $ reverse cpath
  liftThroughTree :: Monad m => ([Int] -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree) -> [Int] -> LinkedTree -> m LinkedTree
  liftThroughTree _ _ l@(Link _ _) = return l
  liftThroughTree f path ln@(LinkedNode i lis children) = LinkedNode i lis <$> traverse (f . (i:)) children
```

Comment: Yes, `LinkedNode` has `Int` as first parameter, I simplified my code while typing it out and forgot to change it there. Should be fixed now.